# What type of exception should I use to avoid No exception type(s) specified

Tags: python, for-loop, pylint, try-except

I have a `list` with these values `['apple', 'banana', '10', 'oranges']`

I want to iterate every element in the list and try to convert it into an `int`.

this is my code so far

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana', '10', 'oranges']

for i in lst:
    try:
        int_ele = int(i)
        print(int_ele)
    except:
        continue
```

Now this code works. But when I run `pylint` on this code I get this error

> W0702: No exception type(s) specified (bare-except)

How should I get rid of this error?

Comment: You can consider switching to `with contextlib.suppress()` since it's cleaner anyways.

Comment: In this case, the only reasonable error is `ValueError`, so you can catch that via `except ValueError` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `except Exception:`, or you can do `except ValueError:`

Comment: ``Exception`` will be very broad, ``ValueError`` should fit in there.